# Find which JS added CSS style to element using Chrome

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to debug some image slideset which turns out with set height on outer div. The height is too short so you see only half of the images. I want to find which JS script sets this height in this div. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. go to DOMElement
2. Right click
3. Break on
4. Attribute modification

Execute your code to see which line changed the attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I did that. I set the breakpoint, refreshed the page, I saw this div in the console, and there are lots of DOM properties. But still I dont see how do I find which script added the inline css height in there?

Comment: If I do this, jquery.min.js only opening in the sources panel, but not the actual jquery written for that element. How to find the exact line of jquery snippet?